# failed to execute /init (error -2) Kernel panic - not syncing: no working init found. Try pasing init= option to kernel. Somehow related to ldconfig

Tags: grub2, init

What I did before the problem.
Having Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, focal). Have installed Visual code, JDK, direnv (10.02.2023). Tried to install a script folowing by instruction. [This is the script][1]. After installing I couldn't use this software (protostar), this error appered:

> Error loading Python lib
> '/root/.protostar/dist/protostar/libpython3.9.so.1.0': dlopen:
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35 not found'

I've installed `libpython3.9` (also this command were ran: `env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.9.2`, as someone recommended), but it didn't help . I tried to install `libc6` - and installed it with `apt install -force`  - no result, same errors. So I found `libc.so.6` and `libc_2.35` (but not libm_2.35) on **Ubuntu 18 repos only**, and added those **outdated repos** into `sources.list` and `sudo update`. Things went worse - `dpkg error...`. Finally `apt install` command become not usable at all. An error was saying something about **ldconfig** problems. So I downloaded `ldconfig` package for ubuntu 20.04 manually and written all it's files to right places, **restored original `sources.list`** for Ubuntu 20.04 and `apt update` `apt upgrade`. Finally it went smoothly and became working.

But I still have to have installed sofware (protostar) working. Someone adviced me to upgrade distro to get it to work. And I have started `sudo do-release-upgrade' - as a result server could not restart.

In the server control panel I've assigned systemrescue ISO and tried to restore the system, but here i do not still have knowledge... The only outcome i see is:

> failed to execute /init (error -2) Kernel panic - not syncing: no working init found.
> Try pasing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.txt for guidance CPU: 0 PID: 1 comm:
> swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-139-generic #156-ubuntu
> ....

On a server there are 2 partitions: grub2 core.img and the main disk is ext4 with all system folders in one.

Of course I have some reasons to restore the server. Thank you.
[1]: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/software-mansion/protostar/master/install.sh